# force full statistic on single table not all db

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, usage-statistics

I'm in need to force a full statistic on a table on a oracle 10g DB

On 11g I can use DBMS_STATS.SET_TABLE_PREFS and set ESTIMATE_PERCENT to 100.

How can I do the same over a 10g Oracle DB?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no method available in Oracle 10g, which you can use to control the default value for some parameters for statistics collection.

The DBMS_STATS.SET_PARAM procedure, can be used to set the values for few defined parameters, but they are cannot be enforced on a specific table, but are applicable for all tables, post their invocation.

You will have to specify the `estimate_percent` as a parameter while gathering stats for your table, as an individual statement (maybe executed, post `GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS`)